# How do I get IntelliJ to load my .rvmrc for a non-ruby based project?

Tags: java, grails, intellij-idea, rvm, rvmrc

I have a Grails project that depends on a couple of ruby gems being installed. All of our developers have RVM installed and thus we have an .rvmrc file in our project directory to switch to the appropriate ruby and gemset.

Is there a way to have IntelliJ automatically read the .rvmrc even though the project needs the SDK to be set to a JDK?

Note: I've looked at the IntelliJ ruby plugin and couldn't see a way to get it to load the .rvmrc but not be the only SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, please [submit a detailed request with the use case](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/RUBY).